# Where can I download JOGL?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm looking to start using Java Open GL, but I can't find it.

Comment: Sounds right, so should it be closed as "Spam"

Comment: JOGL doesn't seem like the sort of thing people would send spam about.

Comment: This is not spam. jogl.dev.java.net contains a mac distro last updated 2008, and points you to jogamp.org. Jogamp.org ... I'm still trying to navigate it. Where's the "download jogl for osx" button?

Comment: I searched for "jogl official download" a bazillin generated search sites pop up all sorts of non official download pages littered with banners and nasty popups and hidden buttons. Their downloads might contain viruses in the native dlls also.  so this is a valid question.

Comment: there are way too many upvotes on this. Why is this question even valid?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried [JOGL's website](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/)?

It looks like their most recent release can be found [here](http://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/rc/), or you can grab a nightly build [here](http://jogamp.org/deployment/autobuilds/master).

Comment: Please edit your answer: given repository is now **obsolete** (as mentioned there), **new** repo is: **`http://kenai.com/projects/jogl/`**

Comment: The links above are obsolete. JOGL is on JogAmp.org.

Comment: A good getting started resource is [here](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial). Specifically, try the [Using JOGL in AWT, SWT, and Swing](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_JOGL_in_AWT_SWT_and_Swing) page. If you're having difficulties running the hello world app (like JVM crash with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION), try the GLJPanel example.

Comment: This answer is not helpful, there's a bazzilion of jars there and I'm not able to find which one has the packages I'm using.

Comment: It actually is helpful, cuz that's where JOGL is!!! I always download one of the jogl_b### ones, but I wonder if I should download one of jogl-master ones! You know, something like the master branch on git...! Anyways, both work fine...

Answer (score 7):

To get the latest stable version of the new JOGL 2.0 beta, go to http://jogamp.org/deployment/webstart/. The nightly builds are at http://jogamp.org/deployment/autobuilds/master/. The most recent auto build (as of this writing) is at http://jogamp.org/deployment/autobuilds/master/jogl-b242-2010-11-28_23-03-07/. You can see a description of their versioning at http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogamp_Versioning_and_Releases.

To get the old JOGL 1.1.1a (the last build before JOGL moved), go to http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-1.1.1a/.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that their website is confusing and hard to find the download link.

When you go to [their website](https://jogl.dev.java.net/), click "Current release build (JSR-231 1.1.1)" or just scroll to the very bottom of the page and you'll see the files. Download the corresponding file for whichever system you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This is what I have found so far:
Go to the wiki:
http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/deployment/JOGL-DEPLOYMENT.html

it indicated that there is a demo directory:
http://jogamp.org/deployment/webstart/

There are a number of JNLP files here. Pick one at random:
http://jogamp.org/deployment/webstart/Gears.jnlp

Open it in the browser. The browser starts up webstart, and webstart installs the 3d extensions and runs the demo. It works, so clearly the libraries are being downloaded - somewhere.

Fine. Let's try it from the command line:
$ curl http://jogamp.org/deployment/webstart/Gears.jnlp > Gears.jnlp
$ javaws Gears.jnlp

Also fine. Great! The trick now is to work out how to link to those libraries that jws has downloaded.

Well ... as far as I can tell they simply get put in /System/Library/Java/Extensions, and ... drat: "Access restriction: The type DirectionalLight is not accessible due to restriction on required library /System/Library/Java/Extensions/j3dcore.jar"

okeydoke, more to figure out yet.

Comment: Hi. DirectionalLight comes from Java3D, not from JOGL. The latest (unofficial) release of Java3D is here: https://github.com/hharrison/java3d-core

Answer (score 1):

Current project home:  http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/